# How can I run Reactjs and Spring boot application simultaneously?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

When I run my spring boot project, I want the React js application to run at the same time. How can I do this?

My React application is an API.

After the user logged in, the warehouses would be listed and the products in the warehouses would also be listed.

There will be spring boot in the back-end and react js on the front-end.

Comment: You have to clarify your question. Is your React app a SPA with an API in Spring?

Comment: My React application is an API.

Comment: Maybe you can try method from this page https://medium.com/codex/run-react-frontend-and-springboot-backend-on-the-same-port-and-package-them-as-a-single-artifact-a790c9e10ac1